# Deploying iPhone Applications on a testing device

Tags: iphone, deployment

I want to outsource my application testing.

Is there a way to send only the binaries (from xcode) to another user, 
and if he gets the right certificate being able somehow to install the app to his device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create an ad-hoc distribution profile through the [Apple Provisioning portal](https://developer.apple.com/iphone/manage/distribution/index.action). You also need to register the device UDID as a test device. Than you can send your tester the provisioning profile and the application bundle, which will allow them to deploy by simple drag/drop to iTunes.

Note that you can specify up to 100 devices in an ad-hoc provisioning profile and those devices count against the per-year quota of test devices.

Answer (score 0):

Apple describes this precisely in the [iPhone Provisioning Portal](https://developer.apple.com/iphone/manage/overview/index.action) documentation. You have to be a registered iPhone developer (with the $99 or more fee) in order to deploy your app on other devices than the ones you use with XCode.

Take a look at the "[Devices](https://developer.apple.com/iphone/manage/devices/howto.action)" section, you have to enter the UDID of the device you want to deploy your code on. Then, for distribution, have a look at the "[Distribution/Ad Hoc](https://developer.apple.com/iphone/manage/distribution/distribution.action)" section.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is the Build-And-Archive function in Xcode - which will also store the dsym file which is essential for crash reports. After the Build-And-Archive, head to the Organizer and you can put the archive into an email with the "Share Application..." button (choose "Archived Applications" on the left).